# Windows Powershell, spaces and stopping mid way

Tags: windows, command-line, powershell

I was changing permissions for some folders files using the "takeown" and "icacls" commands

I was having a problem with the commands giving errors for some of the files, I found out the reason was because some of the subfolders have spaces so I couldn't use the commands on those subfolders without doing them all individually with quotes for the subfolders with spaces.

My questions are:
1. Is there really no way to do all of the subfolders that have spaces in them at once with a command? (there are many subfolders like that and It would take long to do it individually)

2. because of the errors I was getting I closed the Windows Powershell window when it was running the icacls and takeown commands a few times mid way, could that have caused any damage to my files? (there are too many for me to check them individually)

Thank you

Comment: Add double quote in the path in that command.

Comment: The command already had one double quote (") and when I try two ("") the error is invalid argument/option

Comment: Please [edit] the question and add a (sanitized) command example. My _crystal ball_  had broken right now :)